# How can I capture the following repeating data using a regular expression in .Net?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to find the right RegEx to capture some (potentially) repeating data. I don't know how many times it will repeat. If I give an exanple of the data and what I want to capture can anyone point me in the right direction? It's the .Net regex engine (Visual Basic)

The data looks basically like this, and is delimited by $!$ when there is more than one occurance:

**MyFunction('001$$String Description 1$!$002$$String Description 2');**

I want to capture the following groups (of which there could be any number):

1: **001$$String Description 1**

2: **002$$String Description 2**

etc. etc.

I know this can be done with RegEx.Split and probably String.Split, but I still want to know if it's possible in a single capturing RegEx :) Any pointers?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using this regex:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("MyFunction\('(?:(\d+\$\$[^$]+)(?:\$!\$)?)+'\);")
```

and then, after a successful match, something like this:

```
Dim MatchResults As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
If MatchResults.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine("Matched text: {0}", MatchResults.Value)
    For Each capture As Capture In MatchResults.Groups(1).Captures
        Console.WriteLine("   Capture: {0}", capture.Value)
    Next
    MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch()
End While
```

(I don't know VB.NET, though, so I hope I got the syntax right).

Comment: I seem to only get a single match from that one "002$$String Description 2" i.e. the last item?

Comment: The capturing group only contains the last repetition (that is the universal behavior of all regex engines). .NET adds to this a `.Captures` property that contains all the matches the capturing group has gone through. Have you really run the code above?

Comment: Uh, I think I know what might be wrong; the capturing group needs to be repeated itself for this to work. So if you use `"MyFunction\('(\d+\$\$[^$]+(?:\$!\$)?)+'\);"`, it should work, but then the delimiters will be part of the match.